# Variables and Multiple Activities

Tags: android, variables, android-activity

How can I make a variable or object available to multiple activities or restarts of the same one.

Answer (score 1):

This page outlines the tools Android provides for storing data:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Most likely you will want to use `SharedPreferences`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I think I should clarify.  How can I share an InputStream across multiple activities or preserve it across restarts of the current one.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910398/thread-in-java-android